# List Box Update Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a ListBox of constant size 4

I can Add n number of ListBoxItems,Once size exceeds 4 I have enabled  scroll bar,

Problem:when scroll is enabled(more than 4 items), whenever i delete last item, there is a white patch in place of deleted Item.

Patch goes off only when I touch the scroll bar.

I tried ListBox.Invalidate(), But no use

Comment: Are you using the BeginUpdate() method somewhere and forgetting to call the EndUpdate() method (or skipping it because of an exception)?

Comment: No I am not using BeginUpdate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional: This only happens when the last element is selected when it is deleted.

Solution: Explicitly set the new selection, and for the last element make the list scroll first:

```
        int selected = listBox1.SelectedIndex;        
        if (selected >= 0)
        {
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(selected);
            if (selected == listBox1.Items.Count)
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

            listBox1.SelectedIndex = selected - 1;
        }
```

Comment: I am setting new selection(Even afeter Problem persists),I did'not understand the statement    "for the last element make the list scroll first" .
Can you Please elaborate

Comment: It's this statement: `listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

What is your "delete" code to remove from the listbox?  If you are using something like this:

```
listBox.Items[3] = null;
```

...then there are still 4 items in the listbox, just that the 4th one is null.  You actually need to remove the item:

```
listBox.Items.Remove(3);
```

Comment: I am doing listBox.Items.Remove(3) only, Anyhow above answer solved my problem